# Find $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}x^{n+1}$

Tags: calculus, power-series

I need to find f(x) for which:
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}x^{n+1}$$
I tried to use second derivative to get $f^{''}(x)=\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}x^{n-1}$ but I don't really know how to go from here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought it might be instructive to present a way forward that circumvents differentiating the series.  Instead we note simply that

$$\frac1{n(n+1)}=\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}$$

and for $-1<x\le1$

$$\log(x+1)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}x^n$$

Therefore, we find immediately that

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}x^{n+1}&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}x^{n+1}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}x^{n+1}\\\\
&=x\log(x+1)-x+\log(x+1)
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: thats great thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

You have$$f''(x)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-x)^n=\frac{x^2}{1+x}$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: The $x^2$ in the denominator should be $x$.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks a lot!